# Swizzling Vertex Arrays, Vertex Buffer Objects and Shaders

Tags: opengl, vbo, vao

I have a basic understanding of Vertex Arrays, Vertex Buffer Objects and Shaders. However, I am not sure if I can reuse them or whether the association is bijective.

For example:

- Can I use the same Vertex Buffer Object in different Vertex Arrays?
- Can I use the same Vertex Array in different Shaders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can :)

**VBO** - controls where your data is stored

**VAO** - controls layout and binding (you can have several VAO that points to the same VBO, but in different ordering)

**Shaders** - are responsible for doing something with the data, they can be used with different VAO/VBO combinations (but that combination must match attribute layout in the shader of course)

Comment: Thanks. So when I want to use one VAO with multiple shaders, I only need to make sure that the attribute locations are the same? How do I switch the VBO for a VAO? Just by calling `glBindBuffer` after calling `glBindVertexArray`?

Comment: here is a good tutorial on usig VAO: http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial32/tutorial32.html, but basically you can bind new VBO after you bound VAO.